# Issue!!! VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting and unexpected warning in my project.
It seems using ScrollView component and Flatlist together cause the issue

here is the Code

**
<ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={false} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white',padding:10 }}>

```
<View style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
  <FlatList
    data={newsList}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View>
        <View style={{ height: 1, backgroundColor: 'midnightblue', marginTop: 10 }}></View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 15, display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}
        onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('read-news',{news:item})}
        >
          <Image
            source={{ uri: item.urlToImage }}
            style={{ height: 100, width: 100, borderRadius: 10 }}
          />
          <View style={{ marginRight: 130, marginLeft: 10 }}>
            <Text numberOfLines={4} style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.title}</Text>
            <Text style={{ color: 'midnightblue' }}>{item?.source?.name}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )}
  />
</View>
```

**
There are more components that's the reason I need to use ScrollView.
Using Map instead of flatlist can solve the issue. But I prefer Flatlist in the case.
Is there any alternative way to solve the issue?

Comment: Why do you need a nested ScrollView? 
If a FlatList is within a ScrollView which View should react an a swipe?

Comment: FlatList is used in a one component to fetch json data. And  I used scrollview in home.js where exported all components.

Comment: You mean every screens parent is wrapped by a scrollview?

Comment: Yes, I have wrapped by a scrollView